# How to handle NullProviderCultureResult? Isn't it strange to render the homepage without redirection?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization, asp.net-core-7.0

In a Net 7 project I am setting localization in `Program`:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(x => {
  x.AddSupportedCultures("pt", "en");
  x.AddSupportedUICultures("pt", "en");
  x.SetDefaultCulture("pt");
  x.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
  x.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { RouteDataStringKey = "culture" });
});

application.UseRequestLocalization();
```

I have two Razor Pages (Index and About):

```
Index: @page "{culture?}"

About: @page "/{culture?}/about"
```

I am able to access Homepage (Index) using:

```
/
/en
/pt
```

But I am only able to access About page using:

```
/en/about
/pt/about
```

When I try to access "/about" the url is not changed but the homepage is rendered.

Isn't this strange?

Shouldn't redirect to Index and change the Index Url?

Or even Redirect to "/pt/about" because PT is the default culture?

I checked the [RouteDataRequestCultureProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/b8bc661a7429baa89070f3bee636b7fbc1309489/src/aspnetcore/src/Middleware/Localization.Routing/src/RouteDataRequestCultureProvider.cs) source and I has:

```
  if (culture == null && uiCulture == null)
  {
    // No values specified for either so no match
    return NullProviderCultureResult;
  }
```

Can't I define what to do when a `NullProviderCultureResult` occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but at least will explain why it works like this.

> But I am only able to access About page using:

```
/en/about
/pt/about
```

> When I try to access "/about" the url is not changed but the homepage is rendered.

That is basically because the url "/about" is matching with the route `/{culture}` and so it assumes that **"culture=about"**, as a result it redirects to the index page because it matches the route:

```
Index: @page "{culture?}"
```

However, since there is no culture named "about" it renders the default culture "pt" in your case.